# How to prioritise my npm package (library) CSS over users project css?

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-package

I have developed an in-company npm library (designed in React) with many elements. Often, users come and show misaligned elements from my library because their CSS is being prioritized. Is there a way to always force my library's CSS to get prioritized in their projects?

Is there a way apart from a bunch of `important`, I do not want my library CSS to have `important`.

Please share your approach.

Comment: I'm pretty sure if your library gets added after their custom CSS, yours will override.  Also can you use classes to make your stuff have a higher specificity?

Comment: the more you specify the CSS - the higher the priority of the CSS class will be. example: `div.logo` will have higher priority over just `.logo` but lower than `.user div.logo` since `.user div.logo` is more specific. Rather than that or purging - don't think so.